# ArrayList prints out an extra zero as the first element for no reason

Tags: java, arraylist

My program is supposed to check for balanced parentheses inputted from user input. My program involves GUI, but not relevant to the problem. If the inputted parentheses are unbalanced, I also have to return the user the positions of the extra parentheses. I created an ArrayList showing the positions in the inputted string of extra parentheses found. I tested the program and the ArrayList returns starting with a 0 as the first element in it for no reason. Then, it returns the desired answer. Also, it spaces out the numbers far apart  for no reason. Below is my code, however, I only included the code relevant to my question:

[screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKRIm.png)

```
    public boolean balancedParentheses(String inputtedInfo) 
    {
        Stack<Character> stack  = new Stack<Character>();

        for(int i = 0; i < inputtedInfo.length(); i++) 
        {
            char c = inputtedInfo.charAt(i);
            if(c == '(') 
            {     
                stack.push(c);

            } 

            else if(c == ')') 
            {

                if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '(') 
                {
                  return false;

                }


            }



        }
        return stack.isEmpty();

    }

    public String determineProblem(String inputtedInfo)
    {
      List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();
      String str = "";
      int q = 0;     
      int r = 0;


      for(int s = 0; s < inputtedInfo.length(); s++)
      {
         char d = inputtedInfo.charAt(s);

         if (d == '(')
         {
            q += 1;
         }
         else if (d == ')')
         {
            r += 1;
         }
         if (q > r && d == '(')
         {
            positions.add(s);

         }
         else if (r > q && d == ')')
         { 
            positions.add(s);
         }
      }

      String positionsString = "";

      for (int o : positions)
      {
        positionsString += o + "\t";
      }

      if (q > r)
      {
          str = "There are excessive open parentheses! There are " + (q - r) + " extra open parentheses. The offending parentheses are at positions: "
          + positionsString;

      }
      else if (r > q)
      {
         str = "There are excessive closed parentheses! There are " + (r - q) + " extra closed parentheses. The offending parentheses are at positions: "
        + positionsString;
      }

      return str;


    }

    public String printResults()
    {


          String preresults = String.valueOf(balancedParentheses(inputtedInfo));
          String results = "";
          if (preresults == "true")
          {
            results = "You have balanced parentheses!";
          }
          else if (preresults == "false")
          {
            results = "You have unbalanced parentheses!";
          }


          String results2 = determineProblem(inputtedInfo);


          return results + " " + results2;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first iteration of the loop in determineProblem, d is '(' so q gets set to 1. Then you the block

```
if( q > r && d == '(' ){
  positions.add(s);
}
```

Adds 0 to the positions arrayList.

Also: the spacing is because you're including a tab (\t) between each index when you're forming the output string.